# Changes done to .htaccess are not getting reverted back

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, redirect

I am new to WordPress and playing around with it to get some idea about its working. I have done some changes to WordPress' `.htaccess` file to add some redirection and that worked perfectly fine.

Now my problem is even after removing the changes from the .htaccess file, WP is still redirecting me as per the redirection I added up to the file.

I am not sure what other changes I have to do to restore the default working in my WordPress as I even removed the database and than re-installed it but still not able to solve the issue.

Any help in this regard will be much helpful.

Hers is what i added to my htaccess file which i removed later on

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I took the initial refrence from this web-site
[Htaccess File URL Rewriting](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/force-www-nonwww-domain/)

I am using WAMPP server on my local-machine and even after clearing any possible cache i know about, problem still persist.

Comment: Do you have more than one `.htaccess`?

Comment: @m0r7if3r: its on my local machine and i have wampp server so i believe i shd have only one file

Comment: We need more information.
What was in the .htaccess file?
Where is it redirecting from? Where is it redirecting to?

Comment: @SterlingHamilton: i have updated my post please have a look

Comment: Humor me, try adding a ?bustcache=true to the end of your site and see if it still redirects.

Comment: @SterlingHamilton: still its working till i use ?`bustcache=true` in URL and moment i replace it , i am getting redirected to the said URL

Comment: @m0r7if3r: is there any relation with multiple file and redirection,since i tried every way but seems my WAMPP server has made a reference somewhere about that 301 redirect

Comment: @user702325 I don't know what you mean...can you ask that a different way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is still persisting after even reinstalling the database again, than i doubt this is something related to browser cache.
I do not know anything how Word-press or WAMPP work but try to use another browser and also try to clear browser cache.

If even after clearing the cache if still problem persists than i hope some one who knows good about WP might help you.